# Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT B.Value
FROM table1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN table2 B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.Name = 'COMPLETED_AT' 
    AND CONVERT(smalldatetime, A.Value) < GETDATE() - 30
    AND B.Name = 'RESULT'
```

Getting error message

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

when executing the above query

Example table structure

```
ID  Name           Value
1   Result         R12344
1   Completed_At   2015-03-20T06:06:46
2   Result         R23445
2   Completed_At   2014-03-20T06:06:46
```

Column value is of nvarchar(400) datatype

The query result should display the values of result name type which have been made an entry of more than 30 days.

Looking forward in hearing from you.

Comment: I am not converting the value R12344, i am converting only the value when the name = Completed At. its a self join query. i am based on the where condition only the time formats stored in the nvarchar(400) data type would be converted

Comment: In the sample data, you have `Completed At` (with a **space**), while in your query, you use `COMPLETED_AT` (with an underscore) .....

Comment: It just works on my sql server 2005 and 2008 r2, only changed table2 to table1. Maybe you have a table2 with invalid values

Answer (score 1):

Avoid Null In Datetime Coloumn field & fix this error (Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.):

First, I give this type get this error:

```
select * from Tabel1 where  ISNULL(Datecoloumn1,**'0'**)!='1900-01-01 00:00:00'
```

The single quotation Zero is the Problem

I fix like this method :

```
select * from Tabel1 where  ISNULL(Datecoloumn1,**0**) != '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, just changed **Table2** to **Table1**, because you said is a self join.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(12), [Value] varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Name], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'Result', 'R12344'),
    (1, 'Completed_At', '2015-03-20T06:06:46'),
    (2, 'Result', 'R23445'),
    (2, 'Completed_At', '2014-03-20T06:06:46')
;
SELECT B.Value
FROM table1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN table1 B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.Name = 'COMPLETED_AT' 
    AND CONVERT(smalldatetime, A.Value) < GETDATE() - 30
    AND B.Name = 'RESULT'
```

Result

```
Value
R23445
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, When examined the values in the table, i found that few values are stored as 2015-03-20T06:06:46 and few values are stored as 11/25/2014. So now how to compare these both values in where clause with getdate().

Comment: @DevaPrakashBudati You need to do some text parsing and conversion. I encourage to ask a new question about it-